# Virtual environment python causing Django.core not found error

Tags: python, django, virtualenvwrapper

I am currently experiencing problem with the virtual environment.

Using virtual environment wrapper, I used 'workon' to be in that environment. In this enviornment there is a Python 2.7 in Scripts folder and when I run python, it is indeed running this python.

When I run django-admin.py it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JOHN\Envs\courseva\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
     from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

FYI, I installed django and it is within this Envs/courseva folder (Lib/site-packages folder)

now. I was curious so I ran python and in the command I tried 'from django.core import management' and it is not throwing an error and I am really confused now.

I was concerned with the default Python 2.7 in C: so I even changed the environment path but no use. Please help.

Comment: How did you run `django-admin.py`? It looks like it uses the system python instead of the virtual env.. `workon` only activates the environment in the current shell session.

Comment: I did workon and then just typed django-admin.py so should be in the same session though..